# Jquery checked table Row move to top and return on unchecked

Tags: jquery, tablerow

I am very new to JQuery programming needed a small favor from JQuery Experts.
I want the pin-able feature in table row.

Scenario:

1. When I check the checkbox in row, same row move to top of the table.
2. when I uncheck any row which is checked, move to the same place from where it was moved.

jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/safkass/DhpBw/8/

Comment: I'm rewriting your fiddle... Wait a moment...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could use some cleaning up, but this seems to work ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7Xmt2/5/)):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#grid').tablesorter({ widgets: ['staticRow'] });
            $("input").click(function () {
                var row = $(this).parents("tr:first");
                if ($(this).is(':checked', true)) {
                    var firstRow = row.parent().find("tr:first").not(row);
                    var index = row.parent().find("tr").index(row);
                    row.addClass("TopRow");
                    row.insertBefore(firstRow).data("prevIndex", index);
                } else {
                    row.removeClass("TopRow");
                    var rows = row.parent().find("tr");
                    var newPos = $(rows[row.data("prevIndex")]);
                    if (newPos > 0) {
                        row.insertAfter(newPos);
                    }
                }
             });
        });​
```

Comment: Hi steve, thanks for your effort, somehow its working but at same time removing the row also. can you please check it out.

Comment: I updated the answer and the linked fiddle with a fix for that

Answer (score 1):

Here's my fiddle: I believe it works for the purpose of what you want:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DhpBw/14/)

This works even when you check multiple rows or all before unchecking them.

Comment: Hiiii, thanks for your reply and its working fine in FF but in IE its not all working. please check that if possible. thanks in advance.

Comment: Hiiii, thanks for your reply. Its working fine when I just commented consol.log. thanks alot.